# Attempted Rails db association/query between two models is throwing up errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, join, dashboard

I am trying to create an association between two models (Submissions & Agent Activity) whereby each agent can log an activity against a submission without changing the actual submission record itself.

These are my rb files and I believe that these are setup correctly:

```
class Submission < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user, :optional => true

    belongs_to :location, :optional => true

    has_many :agent_activities

end


class AgentActivity < ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :submission, :optional => true #has submission_id foreign key in table
    belongs_to :agent, :optional => true #has agant_id foreign key in 
table


end
```

However, I get lost when it comes to showing this association in the controller. Currently my code looks like this:

```
@submissions = Submission.where(:Desired_Location => current_agent.Company_Business_Location).pluck(:AgentActivity)
```

However, I get this error when i do that

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column "AgentActivity" does not exist 
LINE 1: SELECT "AgentActivity" FROM "submissions" WHERE 
"submissions... ^ : SELECT "AgentActivity" FROM "submissions" WHERE 
"submissions"."Desired_Location" = $1
```

Additionally, when I run

```
Submission.where(:Desired_Location => 
current_agent.Company_Business_Location).map(&:AgentActivity)
```

I get this error:

```
undefined method `AgentActivity' for #<Submission:0x007fc78601e168> 
Did you mean? agent_activities
```

And when I run:

```
AgentActivity.joins(:submission).where('submission.Desired_Location' 
=> current_agent.Company_Business_Location)
```

I get this error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table 
"submission"
LINE 1: ..."."id" = "agent_activities"."submission_id" WHERE 
"submissio...
                                                         ^
: SELECT "agent_activities".* FROM "agent_activities" INNER JOIN 
"submissions" ON "submissions"."id" = 
"agent_activities"."submission_id" WHERE 
"submission"."Desired_Location" = $1
```

Answer (score 0):

`.pluck` returns an array of values from a database column. You don't have `AgentActivity` column in `submissions` table. You can use `map` instead:

```
@submissions = Submission.where(:Desired_Location => current_agent.Company_Business_Location).map(&:AgentActivity)
```

or revert the way you do the query using `join`:

```
AgentActivity.joins(:submision).where('submission.Desired_Location' => current_agent.Company_Business_Location)
```

You may also want to  change association naming to snake case to follow Ruby/Rails conventions:

```
class Submission < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, :optional => true

  belongs_to :location, :optional => true

  has_many :agent_activities # instead of :Agent_activities
end
```

EDIT:

`map` correction:

```
@submissions = Submission.where(:Desired_Location => current_agent.Company_Business_Location).map(&:agent_activity)
```

`join` correction:

```
AgentActivity.joins(:submision).where('submissions.Desired_Location' => current_agent.Company_Business_Location)
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, I have fixed the typo but unfortunately neither of the two solutions work. I am getting an undefined method error for the map query and a statement invalid error for the join query :/

Comment: please, paste full error messages to the question text

Comment: Added fixes to the answer

Comment: Still not working unfortunately. I did try something that did work which was splitting the instance variables into two so one for submissions and one for agent activity (because of mention limits on Stack overflow im removing the @'s) : 
   submissions = Submission.where(:Desired_Location => 
    current_agent.Company_Business_Location)
    agentactivity = AgentActivity.joins(submission)

Comment: @WernerAdewole Try to change your AR query to `AgentActivity.joins(:submision).where('submissions.Desired_Location = ?', current_agent.Company_Business_Location)
`

Comment: @WernerAdewole, I had a look at this and that's the right direction to follow. You should first retrieve your AgentActivity objects and for each of them (if needed) you can then load the associated submission.

The joins method is an efficient way to achieve this. Haven't looked at the details of the errors though sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in class `Submission`

it should be `has_many :agent_activities`

Comment: Thanks for spotting, I have fixed this